# Is there a feature/page where I can see all the questions under my favourite tags?

Tags: feature-request

Let us assume that I have 5 tags added as favourites.

Is there a page where I can see questions that comes under my favourite tags?

i.e., a page/feed that shows recent questions that comes under all of my favourite tags?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** Sort of.

Visit http://stackexchange.com/filters/ and select "Favorite Tags" in the sidebar. (You need to be logged in for this).

This page has a list of all these questions (network-wide), there's a subscribe-by-email in the sidebar, or a Favorite Tags RSS feed link in the bottom right-hand corner.

I don't know if you can do this on a per-site basis.

(Disclaimer: I haven't tried this because I'm at work, but if it doesn't, then file a bug report on Meta.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "Favourite Tags" filter gives the questions of all sites tags questions. But I need per-site questions.

Comment: Didn't there used to be a [tab for these questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/144439)?

Comment: @Wikis: I think the OP is talking about favorite/ignored tags, rather than questions explicitly marked as favorite with the star button.

Comment: @ArunkumarTK there's a whole section on the filter page for "On.." and it gives you the options of all sites, or selected sites.

Comment: @phantom42 I dont know where you are referring to.. There is no option like "On" in filter page., Can you please mention it more precisely?

Comment: @phantom42 The option isn't on the "Favorite Tags" filter

Comment: Weird. My comment form yesterday is missing. I noted that the confusion was coming from what page it's on. It's on the [my filter page](http://stackexchange.com/filters/51996/my-filter). It doesn't seem you can do *all* your favorite tags all at once.